# Strange error getting a JSON element after a JSONP-Ajax request

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

This is my request :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/folder/mypage.aspx',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    },

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
    }                
});
```

and from mypage.aspx (on the .cs) I put out this :

```
Response.Write("{ html: '" + "Hello I'm a string" + "'}");
```

but I get `parsererror - Error: jQuery17100985457205879069_1330089260383 was not called`, so error function is called...

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your response into a "function". It's name is stated in `callback` GET parameter, and you have to use it. So result will be

```
// this function has different name each request
jQuery17100985457205879069_1330089260383({html: "Hello, I'm a string"});
```

so easily, change your line to

```
Response.Write(Request["callback"]+"({ html: \"Hello I'm a string\"});");
```

Comment: I'm on .NET 3.5, can't use that Querystring as method?!?! Or, at least, it is what it says...

Comment: Seems to works! Why this behaviour? It is a jquery standard behaviour with this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning a correct JSONP result.

You need to return the object wrapped in a function call, that calls the function that is specified in the query string. Also, you have to escape the apostrophe in the string as you are using apostrophes to delimit the string:

```
Response.Write(Request.QueryString["callback"] + "({ html: '" + "Hello I\\'m a string" + "'})");
```

Side note: The object in the response is not valid JSON, but it doesn't have to be as it's not parsed as JSON but as Javascript. You could return valid JSON just for good measure:

```
Response.Write(Request.QueryString["callback"] + "({ \"html\": \"" + "Hello I'm a string" + "\"})");
```

Comment: Correct, however, note he's using C# not VB

Comment: @Ingenu: I was at first confused by your comment, as I wrote C# code, but then I noticed that I used parentheses isntead of square brackets for the `Request.QueryString` call. Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 0):

try setting content type something like this
`Respone.ContentType = "application/json"`